# Create folders in wix

Tags: visual-studio-2012, installation, wix, directory

I want to create a folder in C drive and then create some sub folders inside that folder in the wix installer program. But these folders are not related with installed folder. . My program want to install inside the AServiceSetup folder...but i want to create a 'PTLogFile' folder inside the C drive and then want to create some sub folders inside that folder. Please any one help me to correct my code.Following is my code

```
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">

  <Directory Id="PTLogFile" Name="PTLogFile">
    <Directory Id="Backups" Name="Backups"/>
    <Directory Id="CommandLog" Name="CommandLog"/>
    <Directory Id="EventLog" Name="EventLog"/>
    <Directory Id="Responds" Name="Responds"/>
  </Directory>
        <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
            <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="AServiceSetup">
      </Directory>
        </Directory>

    </Directory>
</Fragment>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Thank you for your replies. I got the answer from the above replies
Directory structure as follows

```
 <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
  <Directory Id="LogFile" Name="LogFile">
    <Directory Id="Logs" Name="Logs">
      <Directory Id="Log1" Name="Log1"/>
      <Directory Id="Log2" Name="Log2"/>
      <Directory Id="Log3" Name="Log3"/>
      <Directory Id="Log4" Name="Log4"/>
    </Directory>
  </Directory>
  <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
    <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="AServiceSetup">
    </Directory>
  </Directory>
</Directory>
```

And Component as follows

```
  <Component Id="CreateLogFolders" Guid="....."  Directory="LogFile" >
    <CreateFolder Directory="LogFile" />
    <CreateFolder Directory="Logs"/>
    <CreateFolder Directory="Log1"/>
   <CreateFolder Directory="Log2"/>
   <CreateFolder Directory="Log3"/>
   <CreateFolder Directory="Log4"/>
 </Component>
```

and this component reference inside the feature of the product as follows

```
 <ComponentRef Id="CreateLogFolders"/>
```

Finally add a property inside the product as follows

```
 <Property Id="LogFile" Value="C:" />
```

Answer (score 4):

While you have defined a directory structure, the installer is only going to create directories that are required by components.

A simple option is to add a component like the following:

```
<Component Id="CreateLogFolders" Directory="PTLogFile">
    <CreateFolder Directory="PTLogFile" />
    <CreateFolder Directory="Backups" />
    <CreateFolder Directory="CommandLog" />
    <CreateFolder Directory="EventLog" />
    <CreateFolder Directory="Responds" />
</Component>
```

and reference this component in one of your features.

Comment: thank you for your quick reply...But i got an error as follows.Error 1 ICE18: KeyPath for Component: 'CreateLogFolders' is Directory: 'PTLogFile'. The Directory/Component pair must be listed in the CreateFolders table.

Comment: Still i have the same error remaining. Please refer the below codes and help me...</Component>

  <Component Id="CreateLogFolders" Directory="PTLogFile" Guid="2F15F916-2EEF-4F62-AE23-BC2882A9E12E">
    <CreateFolder Directory="Backups" />
    <CreateFolder Directory="CommandLog" />
    <CreateFolder Directory="EventLog" />
    <CreateFolder Directory="Responds" />
  </Component>
    </ComponentGroup>
</Fragment>

Comment: You need to add <CreateFolder Directory="PTLogFile" /> inside the component

Comment: Hi...Sorry for my silly mistake but still it can't create folders in C drive.

Comment: Hi..It is urgent for me. Can you reply as soon as possible

Answer (score 1):

You'd rather place each `<CreateFolder>` element, which results in a record to [CreateFolder table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa368053.aspx), in its own component. Otherwise, I'm not sure this complies well with [component rules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370561.aspx)...

Leave the directory structure as follows:

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
  <Directory Id="PTLogFile" Name="PTLogFile" />
  <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
     <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="AServiceSetup">
  </Directory>
</Directory>
```

And author the component in the way similar to this:

```
<DirectoryRef Id="PTLogFile">
  <Directory Id="Backups">
    <Component Id="..." Guid="...">
      <CreateFolder />
    </Component>
  </Directory>
  <Directory Id="CommandLog">
    <Component Id="..." Guid="...">
      <CreateFolder />
    </Component>
  </Directory>
  <Directory Id="EventLog">
    <Component Id="..." Guid="...">
      <CreateFolder />
    </Component>
  </Directory>
  <Directory Id="Responds">
    <Component Id="..." Guid="...">
      <CreateFolder />
    </Component>
  </Directory>
</DirectoryRef>
```

Comment: I don't believe that is an issue in this case, since they are only folders, and not actual resources. It's an all-or-nothing case where they are semantically one thing.

Comment: Except Component Rules would say the folder creation would have to ship with that collection of Components forever. You couldn't add or remove (remove probably being more limiting) the set from the Component.  Folders are resources when created directly.

Comment: Fair point, although I still don't know how likely it would be to need to make that change...

Comment: Hi..Thanks for your reply.I want to clear one thing with you that is...I want to keep all setup dlls inside C:/Program/files/AServiceSetup folder. But I want another folder directory to keep my log details in C:/PTLogFile. In side this PTLogFile...I want to create four folders as i mention above.